# Converting string of lists to list of string in java

Tags: java

I am getting a value as list of string in string format like this: "["a", "b"]". I would like to convert them to a list of strings. I can do this by stripping the leading and trailing braces and then splitting on comma. But here the problem is that I may receive the same value as single string also "a" that too I want to convert to a list of strings. So is there any way to generalize this.

Comment: Splitting a string without the delimiter isn't a problem. A bigger problem with that strategy is if the delimiter appears between the quotes.

Comment: Sounds like you're asking how to parse a JSON array.

Comment: Try to break the each element and add each element to `Set` so you'll get unique value.

Comment: If i understood your question correctly . why don't you get the string which is inside the double quotes and add to list or set.

Comment: It may be a JSONArray and it may be JSONString. I have been wondering is there any way I can generalize.

Comment: You can use regex...

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use `Regex`.

Your expression can look like this: `"(.+?)"`

`.+?` matches any character (except for line terminators)

`+?` **Quantifier** - Matches between *one* and *unlimited* times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed.

---

```
String tokens = "[\"a\", \"b,c\", \"test\"]";
String pattern = "\"(.+?)\"";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = p.matcher(tokens);

List<String> tokenList = new ArrayList<String>();
while (m.find()) {
    tokenList.add(m.group());
}

System.out.println(tokenList);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can generalize the following:
`String str = "\"[\"a\",\"b\"]\"";
        String[] splitStrs = str.split("\"",7);
        System.out.println(splitStrs[0]+" "+splitStrs[1]+" "+splitStrs[2]+" "+splitStrs[3]+" "+splitStrs[4]+" "+splitStrs[5]+" "+splitStrs[6]);`

My output

> [ a , b ]

Comment: Splitting a string without the delimiter isn't a problem. A bigger problem with that strategy is if the delimiter appears between the quotes.